# in general, in javascript, isn't using innerHTML an [in]security issue?

Tags: javascript, security, sql-injection, innerhtml

with the `DOM` and cool new tools such as `reactjs`, should `innerHTML` ever be used in a `javascript` program?

using it is a lot like opening oneself to an SQL injection attack, but here it's a cross-site scripting etc. everything needs to be examined and scrubbed before it's used.

seems to me `innerHTML` has the same security issues as `eval()` and should be avoided for [in]security reasons.

(also aesthetically, but that's just me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `innerHTML` is often misused and a very common source of client-side HTML-injection (DOM-XSS) security holes.

It's usually better to use object-style creation methods, such as `createElement`, `textContent` and setting direct DOM properties. Similarly in jQuery, prefer to set variable content using `.text()` and `.prop()` rather than `.html()`, or passing HTML markup to the manipulation methods that allow it.

There are some exceptions though:

- if you're using a client-side templating language that deals with HTML-escaping for you automatically (eg lodash templates with `<%-`), it's safe to write the output to `innerHTML`.
- if you're appending a lot of siblings to a single element and performance is a priority (the usual example being a `<table>` with a large number of rows), HTML markup creation can be worth it and you will just have to be careful to HTML-escape all the text manually
- where the content is actually supposed to be HTML, for example you have data that has been processed from Markdown.

Comment: the first and third cases are the same: you're relying on (someone else's) a code scrubber for your security. in the case of the markdown, it seems more of a bug than a feature that the output is html. the second case seems to be a browser anomaly: that currently html text renders faster than DOM manipulation, something that should get better as pages are becoming more dynamic.