# Allow user to add buttons to html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page that I run locally in the web browser, and in the code I have a series of links. The links are wrapped around buttons, and the buttons are styled using CSS. I frequently have to add links, so I would like to put a "new link creator" directly on the page and create a button based on a url entered into the box. Here are some of the links and the code around them:

```
<div class='m'>
    <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Stack Overflow'></a>
    <a href='https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Puzzling Stack Exchange'></a>
    <a href='https://pastebin.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Pastebin'></a>
    <a href='https://github.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='GitHub'></a>
    <a href='https://scholar.google.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Google Scholar'></a>
    <a href='https://google.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Google'></a>
    <a href='https://encrypted.google.com/' target='_blank'><input type='button' class='menu' value='Encrypted Google'></a>
</div>
```

And here is the progress I've made so far on solving the problem (basically nothing):

```
<div class='tb'>
    <input type='text' id='get_url'></input>
    <input type='button' value='Create New Button' onclick='newbutton();'></input>
</div>
```

Which points to this JS:

```
function newbutton() {
    var url = document.getElementById('get_url');
    // ... make button with the given url
    }
```

any help is appreciated. if I need to include any more code (e.g. my CSS) just let me know in the comments.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrd25zw9/1/)

Comment: you can do that once you refresh the page it will be gone

Comment: I know that, it's okay - I don't want them to be permanent.

Answer (score 1):

```
function newbutton() {
    var div = document.querySelector('.m');
    var input = document.querySelector('#get_url');
    // ... make button with the given url

    var dom = '<a href="' + input.value + '" target="_blank">';
    dom += '<input type="button" class="menu" value="new button"></a>';

    div.innerHTML += dom;
}
```

Here's the code that can create new button element, but there're some steps you need to consider by yourself. It's just an one of basic ideas.

> 1. URL formatting

The code above only recognizes the exact url, such as `https://google.com`. If the url isn't correct, the button wouldn't recognize it and redirect you to there. So, you should think of the algorithm for covering the all possible cases.

> 2. Data wouldn't be saved.

Even though you've created a new button containing the new url, it's not going to be stored in your web, since the behavior of generating the new DOM is just from a function. Which means, your original HTML file does not include it by default. So, if you want to store it as well, you better consider the database or webStorage.

> 3. There's a better way to create a DOM, instead of `innerHTML`

I've used `innerHTML` to create a DOM. However, what if there is/are better way(s)? Using `innerHTML` isn't really a good choice to make a DOM, even though it seems quite useful and handy. There're several reasons and you may check these links below. I am not going to explain all the differences deeply, since your question wasn't on it, but to just let you know. There're other options, so I recommend you to figure the differences out!

- innerHTML
- innerText
- textContent
- createElement()
- createTextnode()
- etc

[in general, in javascript, isn't using innerHTML an [in]security issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226317/in-general-in-javascript-isnt-using-innerhtml-an-insecurity-issue)

[innerText vs innerHtml vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)

[Security comparison of eval and innerHTML for clientside javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860287/security-comparison-of-eval-and-innerhtml-for-clientside-javascript)

Comment: Woah! Downvote because of using `innerHTML` to create HTML elements instead of `createElement`.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Thank you for your comment. Well, I was  updating the answer about the difference of them

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I've edited my answer and mentioned on innerHTML, so could you take your downvote back?

Comment: Done! Great edit. Upvoting now :P

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Thank you!