# Wrap element around children of main element. JQLite

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I'm using angular and JQLite. I have an element `<md-button my-attr>MyText<md-icon>close</md-icon>` with a attribute directive.

In my attr directive I want to wrap `<div layout=row flex></div>` around the `<md-button>` children.

I used `wrap(), children().wrap()`, I tried replacing the contents() with a wrapped contents(). The problem I keep having is:

```
<md-button my-attr><div layout=row flex>MyText</div><div layout=row flex><md-icon>close</md-icon></div></md-button>
```

I need 1 div wrapped around both of them.

```
<md-button><div layout=row flex>MyText<md-icon>close</md-icon></div></md-button>
```

// $element is 
// I tried several things, this is the last thing I tried.

```
        var content = $element.children().wrap('<div layout=row flex></div>');
        $element.empty();
        $element.append(content);
```

To clarify.

`<md-button>` is $element. I want to wrap the children of $element in a single div. so `<md-button><child/><child/><child/></md-button>` becomes `<md-button><div><child/><child/><child/></div></md-button>`

Comment: Show more of the code that is producing the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       var content = "<div layout=row flex>" + $element.html() + "</div>";
        $element.empty();
        $element.append(content);
```

Was able to get it from:
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838201/263457)

Answer (score 1):

```
directive('myDirective',[function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    scope:{},
    link:function(scope,element,attr){
      element.wrap('<div class=".outer"></div>');
    }
  };
}]);
```

This will wrap your element with a div that has a class .outer. Use it like this
`<div my-directive>Element</div>`

Comment: That's not want I want. I want to wrap the element's children in a div. Not the element. It must be this way because I'm using angular-material and need to apply a layout div to the children, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<md-button>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
</md-button>
```

and you want get

```
<md-button>
  <div>
    <child/>
    <child/>
    <child/>
  </div>
</md-button>
```

then try this

```
element.html(angular.element('<div></div>').html(element.contents()));
```