# How to add <p> tags using javascript to a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

I want make a  that auto scrolls and I want to be able to add paragraph tags to it using javascript.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In SO community if you want to have a question answered, you have to show that you tried doing it yourself. This site isnt intended to do assignments for you. Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure javascript method to wrap content in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [ask] in the Help Center and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js) plugin for javascript, you can achieve this like that:

```
var myDiv = $("#IdOfYourDiv");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.textContent = "something";
myDiv.append(paragraph);
```

but next time, pelase insert your html/javascript code, nobody have a crystal ball to know how you are writing your code to help you  ;)

Comment: Thank you, I am new to stack overflow and coding, next time I will insert some code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = 'I am p Tag';
    div[0].append(p);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
    <div> I am div Tag</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

> Depending on properties of your div like Id, name, class, u can also use
>   document.getElementById etc.