# How can I wrap children elements inside a div with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

For instance, I have the following code

```
<div class="parent>
  <p> Item 1 </p>
  <p> Item 1 </p>
  <p> Item 1 </p>
</div>
```

I want turn the code above into the following code with pure javascript

```
<div class="parent>
  <div class="parent-child>
    <p> Item 1 </p>
    <p> Item 1 </p>
    <p> Item 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure javascript method to wrap content in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You better use `id` rather than `class` as identifiers. However, here is the working code for you.

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
var children = parents[0].innerHTML;
var newContent = '<div class="parent-child">' + children + '</div>';
parents[0].innerHTML = newContent;
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p> Item 1 </p>
  <p> Item 1 </p>
  <p> Item 1 </p>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I see someone gave a link to a similar answer. Feel free to use either