# How to wrap contents of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     ...contents...
</div>
```

I'd like to do this using JavaScript:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents-wrapper">
     ...contents...
  </div>
</div>
```

I did a quick Google search, but couldn't find what I was looking for. Is there a simple way to do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

**EDIT**

The current answer wraps all the contents in a div rather than just wrapping all the contents all together in one div.

Current code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="contents-wrapper">
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="contents-wrapper">
     <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want achieved:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="contents-wrapper">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure javascript method to wrap content in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div)

Comment: @AliKleit No it does not, my question is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wrap the contents of `wrapper` you can simply use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method like:

```js
$(".wrapper").contents().wrap("<div class='contents-wrapper'></div>");
```

```css
.contents-wrapper {
  background: skyblue;
  padding:10px;
}

.wrapper{
  background: #CCC;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
     ...contents...
</div>
```

---

To wrap just the outer div of contents, you can use [`.wrapInner()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) method like:

```js
$(".wrapper").wrapInner("<div class='contents-wrapper'></div>");
```

```css
.contents-wrapper {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">A</div>
  <div class="inner">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems like this will wrap all the contents in the div, can't I wrap just the outer div of contents?

Comment: We can. Please update your post with a simple example and what happens now with current code and what is the expected output also.

Comment: Code updated. Also, if you have any further issues, please create a separate question for that, so that there is a separation of concern and future users can get specific answers for a specific issue while searching SO. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) api

```js
$(".wrapped").wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: green;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapped">
  <div> I am wrapped & got style from wrapper div </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use pure javascript and use innerHTML

```js
let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapped')[0];
let innerContent = ele.innerHTML;
ele.innerHTML = '';
let crtEle = `<div class ="wrapper">${innerContent}</div>`;
ele.innerHTML = crtEle;
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapped">
  <div> I am wrapped & got style from wrapper div </div>
</div>
```