# Generate an HTML wrapper after opening and before closing parent tags

Tags: javascript

I'd like to generate a wrapper that's a child of a shared class, but it's the immediate parent of the whatever HTML markup is added in. It will save time creating a bunch of wrapper divs and the purpose of this is to create specific layouts, backgrounds, etc.

Simply put, for example, any class of .page should generate the wrapper but also generate around whatever markup that goes inside it. Would need something like this:

```
<div class="page">
   <div class="wrapper"> <!-- GENERATED WRAPPER -->
     <!-- This is where any markup can go -->
   </div><!-- GENERATED WRAPPER -->
</div>
```

I wasn't sure if PHP would be a better, more secure method but the closest thing I could find was: [See Michal's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838104/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div) Not sure how I would apply a loop to get this to work, any ideas would help. Thanks. Also, pure JS only please.

Comment: if you can tolerate a non-native solution, jQuery's [`.wrapInner`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) method appears to do what you're asking for.

Comment: The whole idea is to go pure JS, learn it and keep the file sizes/script loading to a minimum as this will be part of a production. I've tried insertAdjacentHTML() as it doesn't corrupt any elements inside but quickly realized this automatically closes tags and cannot split the tags (as far as I've searched). For now, just adding in the HTML manually would be a better solution in this case.

Comment: I've added a pure JS answer that wraps whatever existing content is already in the element with the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Works in major browsers, wraps properly and is very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although better methods may exist, this should work on every current browser.

It works by finding every `.page` element, creating an initially empty wrapper element, and then appending each child node of the original element into the wrapper (nb: the append operation causes the child to be removed from its original parent, after which the next remaining sibling automatically becomes the first child).

Once done, it finally inserts the wrapper element (which now contains all of the original children) into the DOM as the sole new child.

```js
const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
for (const p of pages) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  while (p.firstChild) {
    wrapper.appendChild(p.firstChild);
  }
  p.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```css
.page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div>Page 1</div>
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div>Page 2</div>
  <p>Para 1</p>
  <p>Para 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');

const createWrapper = () => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString('<div class="wrapper"><nav><ul><li><a href="#">Link</a></li></ul></nav></div>', 'text/html');
  return doc.body;
}

pages.forEach(el => {
  const wrapper = createWrapper();
  const newMarkup = wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: never use deserialisation and concatenation on DOM objects - it _destroys_ the original elements (and any event handlers associated with them) and then recreates them.   It's far better to use DOM methods to move the child nodes inside their new parent element,

Comment: @Alnitak this whole question should not be done either way.